# Custom Visual Studio Debug Engine for Simulator

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I have a requirement for developing a debugger extension for Visual Studio.  The code is in C++, however, it is run in a simulator environment.  The application is capable of receiving break points and displaying variable information. 
I have looked into the Concord API, but it seems rather complex.  Do I have to develop an Expression Evaluator, even though the code is in C++?
Basically I just want the program to run and hit the breakpoints that the user has created for starters.

Should I try and write a visual studio extension instead?  Although I don't see any way of halting execution of a program in debug mode?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah the joy of writing a custom debugger! I'm writing one now. See the visual studio custom debug engine sample to start with. Python Tools for Visual Studio, MIDebugEngine are more complex but also more complete and production code. Much easier to write the debugger in C#.

Some blogs that helped me a lot.

https://limbioliong.wordpress.com/2011/08/30/creating-a-com-server-using-c/

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jmstall/2009/07/09/icustomqueryinterface-and-clr-v4/

VS2005 SDK PDF has more detailed debugger documentation.

VS2015/17 C# Extension projects has a custom project type package which comes with a script debugger launcher to start with.